# Rails 6 undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass when creating an object associated by non-standard foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two models `Wallet` and `FakeWallet` associated with `identifier` and `external_id` like below:

```
#models

class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  has_one    :fake_wallet, foreign_key: :identifier, primary_key: :external_id
end

class FakeWallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wallet, foreign_key: :identifier, primary_key: :external_id, optional: true
end
```

When trying to add a new record via `Wallet.last.fake_wallet.create!(balance: 7890)` I'm getting an error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass)

If foreign key is not standard this action is not possible or did I wrongly bind the models? Below my schema:

```
#schema.rb

  create_table "wallets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "wallet_type"
    t.string "external_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "fake_wallets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal "balance", default: "0.0"
    t.string "identifier"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method built `has_one` doesn't ever return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so this kind of chaining does not work. Instead `has_one` adds dedicated methods to your model for this, named `create_<name>` and `create_<name>!`.

So in your example, you would instead call…

```rb
Wallet.last.create_fake_wallet!(balance: 7890)
```

For more information, [here is the relevant documentation for the methods `has_one` creates](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one).